# MySQL get comma separated rows of record ids which lies between given condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having difficult time building a logic. I have a MySQL table with data more or less similar as follows. Data are sorted by Date field.

```
ID      Code  Type  Date 
4       PQR     0   2019-10-17 22:30:00
7       PQR     0   2019-10-17 21:30:00
3       XYZ     0   2019-10-17 20:30:00
1       ABC     1   2019-10-17 19:30:00
5       PQR     0   2019-10-17 18:30:00
6       PQR     0   2019-10-17 17:30:00
2       PQR     0   2019-10-17 16:30:00
8       PQR     0   2019-10-17 15:30:00
9       XYZ     0   2019-10-17 14:30:00
14      ABC     0   2019-10-17 13:30:00
11      XYZ     0   2019-10-17 12:30:00
12      RPM     2   2019-10-17 11:30:00
13      PQR     0   2019-10-17 10:30:00
10      PQR     0   2019-10-17 09:30:00
15      PQR     0   2019-10-17 08:30:00
18      XYZ     0   2019-10-17 07:30:00
17      ABC     1   2019-10-17 06:30:00
16      XYZ     0   2019-10-17 05:30:00
19      XYZ     0   2019-10-17 05:00:00
24      XYZ     0   2019-10-17 04:45:00
21      PQR     0   2019-10-17 04:30:00
26      PQR     0   2019-10-17 04:00:00
23      PQR     0   2019-10-17 03:45:00
20      PQR     0   2019-10-17 03:30:00
25      PQR     0   2019-10-17 03:15:00
22      ABC     0   2019-10-17 03:00:00
```

What I want to accomplish is -

1. Get Comma Separated IDs of all rows having Code=PQR, between rows which has Code=ABC, Type=0 and Code=ABC, Type=1
2. So the result would look like -

> ```
> | FromID | ToCode |       PQRIds      |
> +--------+--------+-------------------+
> |  22    |   17   |   21,26,23,20,25  |
> +--------+--------+-------------------+
> |  17    |   14   |         13,10,15  |
> +--------+--------+-------------------+
> |  14    |    1   |          5,6,2,8  |
> ```

Update

-Between 22-ABC-0  and 17-ABC-1  There are few PQR

-Between 17-ABC-1  and 14-ABC-0  There are few PQR

-Between 14-ABC-0  and 1-ABC-1  There are few PQR

Comment: insert into Table2(PQRIds) value(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM Table2 where Code='PQR')

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: @Nick Mysql 5.7

Comment: Your output does not make sense unless id 14/abc type is mistakenly set to 0(should be 1) AND can you please add the date column.

Comment: @P.Salmon, I have added Date column, if you go through my edits and question again, it completely make sense

Comment: This statement 'Get Comma Separated IDs of all rows having Code=PQR, between rows which has Code=ABC, Type=0 and Code=ABC, Type=1' - is incorrect - should read something like from code = abc to next abc - type is irrelevant (unless you want from abc to next abc where type code changes)

Comment: @P.Salmon yes where from ABC to another ABC where type code changes from 0 to 1 and then 1 to 0, that is what I meant

Answer (score 0):

1) allocate a block number and row number for each abc 2) aggregate 3) find the id by matching row numbers

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(ID   int,   Code varchar(3), Type int,dt datetime);
insert into t (id,code,type,dt) values  
(4    ,   'PQR'  ,   0  , '2019-10-17 22:30:00'),
(7    ,   'PQR'  ,   0  , '2019-10-17 21:30:00'),
(3    ,   'XYZ'  ,   0  , '2019-10-17 20:30:00'),
(1    ,   'ABC'  ,   1  , '2019-10-17 19:30:00'),
(5    ,   'PQR'  ,   0  , '2019-10-17 18:30:00'),
(6    ,   'PQR'  ,   0  , '2019-10-17 17:30:00'),
(2    ,   'PQR'  ,   0  , '2019-10-17 16:30:00'),
(8    ,   'PQR'  ,   0  , '2019-10-17 15:30:00'),
(9    ,   'XYZ'  ,   0  , '2019-10-17 14:30:00'),
(14   ,   'ABC'  ,   0  , '2019-10-17 13:30:00'),
(11   ,   'XYZ'  ,   0  , '2019-10-17 12:30:00'),
(12   ,   'RPM'  ,   2  , '2019-10-17 11:30:00'),
(13   ,   'PQR'  ,   0  , '2019-10-17 10:30:00'),
(10   ,   'PQR'  ,   0  , '2019-10-17 09:30:00'),
(15   ,   'PQR'  ,   0  , '2019-10-17 08:30:00'),
(18   ,   'XYZ'  ,   0  , '2019-10-17 07:30:00'),
(17   ,   'ABC'  ,   1  , '2019-10-17 06:30:00'),
(16   ,   'XYZ'  ,   0  , '2019-10-17 05:30:00'),
(19   ,   'XYZ'  ,   0  , '2019-10-17 05:00:00'),
(24   ,   'XYZ'  ,   0  , '2019-10-17 04:45:00'),
(21   ,   'PQR'  ,   0  , '2019-10-17 04:30:00'),
(26   ,   'PQR'  ,   0  , '2019-10-17 04:00:00'),
(23   ,   'PQR'  ,   0  , '2019-10-17 03:45:00'),
(20   ,   'PQR'  ,   0  , '2019-10-17 03:30:00'),
(25   ,   'PQR'  ,   0  , '2019-10-17 03:15:00'),
(22   ,   'ABC'  ,   0  , '2019-10-17 03:00:00');

Select fromid,toid,gc from
(
select bn,group_concat(case when code = 'pqr' then id end order by dt desc) gc,
         min(rownumber) minrownumber, max(rownumber) + 1 maxrownumber
from
(
select t.*,
         if(code = 'abc', @bn:=@bn+1,@bn:=@bn) bn,
         @rn:=@rn+1 rownumber,
         @p:=code p
from t
cross join (select @bn:=0,@rn:=0,@p:=0) r
order by dt
) s
group by bn 
) t1
join 
(select t.id fromid,t.code fromcode,
         @rn1:=@rn1+1 rownumber
from t
cross join (select @rn1:=0) r
order by dt
) t2
on t2.rownumber = t1.minrownumber
join 
(select t.id toid,t.code tocode,
         @rn2:=@rn2+1 rownumber
from t
cross join (select @rn2:=0) r
order by dt
) t3
on t3.rownumber = t1.maxrownumber;

+--------+------+----------------+
| fromid | toid | gc             |
+--------+------+----------------+
|     22 |   17 | 21,26,23,20,25 |
|     17 |   14 | 13,10,15       |
|     14 |    1 | 5,6,2,8        |
+--------+------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.12 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton!, I will check and respond back. Also what if I want to limit the date, for example, I want to consider to search in records where date is older than 2 years.??

Answer (score -2):

I think you are looking for `group_concat`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

```
GROUP_CONCAT([DISTINCT] expr [,expr ...] 
[ORDER BY {unsigned_integer | col_name | expr}
[ASC | DESC] [,col_name ...]] 
[SEPARATOR str_val])
```

```
mysql> SELECT student_name,
 GROUP_CONCAT(test_score) 
FROM student 
GROUP BY student_name;
```